# How to show all languages in a request?

Tags: c#, octokit.net

**octokit.net**

To filter the query by language I do this

```
var request = new SearchRepositoriesRequest("mvc client side framework")
{
   // how about we restrict the language the library is written in?
    Language = Language.JavaScript
}
```

How to make all languages ​​appear in the request again?
Something like:

```
Language = Language.All
```

Comment: `request.Language = Language.All;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property `Language` is nullable, so maybe `Language = null`?

Comment: Are you familiar with "octokit.net"?
Could you help me with a question - `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52728418/how-to-get-at-least-some-data-on-the-repository-license`   and link - `https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/issues/1881`