# How to get at least some data on the repository license?

Tags: c#, octokit

I search for repositories according to the documentation. 
https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/blob/master/docs/search.md
How to get at least some data on the repository license?
I mean get data from this page.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqgeX.png)

Or the content of the file - "LICENSE.txt"

I need information from any of the areas indicated in the figure.
I try to do on using the code, but I don’t understand how to do it correctly

```
var repoLicen = client.Repository.GetLicenseContents("octokit", "octokit.net");  
var licen = repoLicen.li???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var licenseContents = github.Repository.GetLicenseContents("octokit", "octokit.net").Result;
```

GetLicenseContents returns Task this means that the method is asynchronous.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: What do you want to say about the asynchronous method?
I did this (see the code). Correctly? Or it is possible to do more correctly?  `private async void licens()
        {   
            var repoLicen = client.Repository.GetLicenseContents("octokit", "octokit.net").Result;            
            string licenName = repoLicen.License.Name.ToString();            
        }        
        private async void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            licens();
        }`   I'm starting to figure out programming.
I apologize if the question is incorrect

Comment: Use `private async Task<RepositoryContentLicense> licens() => await client.Repository.GetLicenseContents("octokit", "octokit.net");`